# how to implement data freeze option in dashboard development for chart analyses

Tags: spring, d3.js, freeze, dashboard, sapui5

hi i am working on dashboard. i have two screens named summary and detailed. for every 5 min dashboard screens getting new data from Database. my requirement is i need data freeze button on my dashboard screen. which stops sending requests(5 min interval) for making analysis on screen.

if i click freeze button on my summary screen and click on bar of bar chart which navigates respective detailed screen. now detailed screen sending request for server and getting data from database**(which may be new data and not matching with summary data).**

data in summary and detailed screens should be consistent when data freeze option is selected. please help me to solve this problem.

my code is too large so i am providing here my code summary

in my summary screen i am calling ajax call to get chart data

```
summary.controller.js

var jsonObjToSend = {} ;
jsonObjToSend["dialogue"] = "summary";
timeIntervalVarSummary = setInterval(function(){
            this.doAjax("/sysdashbplugin/getKeyEquipmentChartData",jsonObjToSend).done(this.updateKeyEqChart);
            },300000);
updateKeyEqChart: function(modelData) {
    // code to draw bar chart
}
```

if i click on any one of the bar chart it will open new tab which having detailed information of respected bar

```
detailed.controller.js

var jsonObjToSend = {} ;
jsonObjToSend["dialogue"] = "detailed";
timeIntervalVarDetail = setInterval(function(){
            this.doAjax("/sysdashbplugin/getDetailsOfBar",jsonObjToSend).done(this.drwaTable);
            },300000);

drwaTable: function(modelData) {
    // code to draw Openui5 table 
}
```

now if i click on data freeze button in summary screen timeIntervalVarSummary will be clear and will not get new data assume UHT bar caontains 40%

after 10 min Db may be updated like UHT value 60% ,but still in summary screen it 40% only because timeIntervalVarSummary is cleared and i am not requesting to server

after 10 min if i click on UHT bar my detailed screen tab will open and get executed detailed.controller.js

now request in detailed.controller.js will get UHT detail info like 60% BUT i need only 40% becase i freezed